# Fetching multiple paragraph text from database

Tags: html, database, google-chrome, internet-explorer, paragraph

I have a website where users can add comments and I am storing those comments in SQL server database. The field where I am storing the comments is nvarchar(4000). While testing I found that I had to press 'Enter' 3 times to get the desired paragraph formatting (when I view in Chrome). Usually in text editors like notepad I have to press 'Enter' 2 times to write next paragraph.

I checked in database and it looks like the text is stored as having paragraph breaks just as I want. The weird thing is that when I open my website in IE, I have no paragraph, just continuous plain text.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Why do I have to press 'Enter' 3 times to get the same formatting which is similar to pressing 'Enter' 2 time in notepad?
2. Why is IE not having any paragraph breaks?

Thanks.

Comment: In developer tools, I see that Chrome renders multiple <p></p> to have that format but IE only shows a single <p></p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by replacing the carriage character and new line character as:

```
mytext.ToString().Replace("\r\n","<br/>")
```